# Python lxml - can't get to parent

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have an xml tree that I need to search:

```
<instance>
    <hostName>hostname1</hostName>
    <port enabled="true">9010</port>
    <metadata>
        <branch>master</branch>
    </metadata>
    <vipAddress>vip.address.com</vipAddress>
</instance>
<instance>
    <hostName>hostname2</hostName>
    <port enabled="true">9011</port>
    <metadata>
        <branch>sub_branch</branch>
    </metadata>
    <vipAddress>vip2.address.com</vipAddress>
</instance>
```

I am trying to do a search via the text in branch then get the grandparent element and get the `vipAddress` and `port` but when I use the code below when I try and print the `vipAddress` and the `port` it prints all of them instead of the one I was actually looking for:

```
branch_name = 'master'    
for record in tree.xpath('//branch/text()'):
  if(record == branch_name):
     branch = record.getparent()
     target_environment = branch.xpath('//vipAddress/text()')
     print(target_environment)
     target_port = branch.xpath('//port/text()')
```

example:

If I was to search for `master` instead of returning `target_environment=vip.address.com` and `port=9011` it will return `target_environment=[vip.address.com, vip2.address.com]` and `port=[9010,9011]`

I am sure I am doing something simple wrong I just can't see what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the best at working with xml in python, but I do see a few issues:

`for record in tree.xpath('//branch/text()'):` converts your branch elements to string, which you use further down to compare to `branch_name`.   Strings do not have a `getparent()` method, so you may want to remove the `text()` from the xpath and compare `branch_name` to `record.text`

Once your `record` is an element, calling `getparent()` twice on record will give you it's grandparent element `instance`.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but it seems to work.

`.xpath('//')` searches for items matching the query anywhere.  Since you just want the element that's a child of `<instance>`, `branch.xpath('vipAddress/text()')` should do.  Same goes for finding the target_port.

Also I think .xpath always returns a list, so even if this all works your `port` will look like `[9011]`

Putting it together I get something like:

```
branch_name = 'master'
for record in tree.xpath('//branch'):
  if(record.text == branch_name):
     branch = record.getparent().getparent()
     target_environment = branch.xpath('vipAddress/text()')
     print(target_environment)
     target_port = branch.xpath('port/text()')
     print(target_port)
```